# "A" or "B" in switch statements?

Tags: templating, switch, case

Is it possible to provide different possible values per case?

I've tried the following formats without success.

```
{% case "A" or "B" or "C" %}
  {# run this if case matches A or B or C #}
```

I saw this done somewhere else so I thought I'd give it a shot

```
{% case "A" %}
{% case "B" %}
{% case "C" %}
  {# run this if case matches A or B or C #}
```

From the documentation it doesn't seem like this would be possible but wanted to check just in case. If not, any chance we'll see this sometime in the future?

Comment: Here's the feature request page for anybody who wants to have this functionality added: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7632651-add-or-operator-support-for-switch-statements

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### As of [Craft 2.6](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2771), this is now possible!

In fact, it works exactly like your first example:

```
{% case "A" or "B" or "C" %}
  {# run this if case matches A or B or C #}
```

---

#### Original answer...

<s>**Your first example** is not currently possible, but might make for a good [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/).</s>

**Your second example** is not possible, and most likely never will be. If it were added in the future, that would likely have a major (breaking) impact on all existing uses of the `switch` statement.

The way that Craft has implemented the `case` statement is by making it completely unnecessary to supply a `break` statement. In fact, the `break` statement doesn't even exist natively (though can be added with the [MN Break and Continue](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue/) plugin). The `case` statement will automatically end when it hits the next `case` statement, or the `endswitch` statement.

**An actual solution** would be to use a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) or [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html). If you have multiple `case` statements which should trigger the same behavior, I'd recommend wrapping that behavior into a macro/include, and calling that macro/include for each relevant `case`.

Comment: Thanks Lindsey! I wasn't aware of macros, they'll be a lot of help. And I'll go ahead and submit it as a feature request; I'm sure it'll come in handy in the future.